# Is the Airflow BranchDateTimeOperator > or >= for the upper and lower bounds?

Tags: airflow

Suppose I execute this `BranchDateTimeOperator` on the following schedules (`ds` values). Which tasks will be executed and which will be skipped?

```py
branch_task = BranchDateTimeOperator(
    task_id='create_records_attributed',
    depends_on_past=True,
    use_task_execution_date=True,
    follow_task_ids_if_true=['task_a'],
    follow_task_ids_if_false=['task_b'],
    target_upper=datetime(2022, 5, 20),
    target_lower=None,
    dag=dag,
)
```

- `datetime(2022, 5, 19)`
- `datetime(2022, 5, 20)`
- `datetime(2022, 5, 21)`

Answer (score 0):

In your example `task_a` will be followed if `target_lower < now < target_upper` otherwise `task_b` will follow.

`BranchDateTimeOperator` makes more sense if used with [`use_task_execution_date=True`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/602abe8394fafe7de54df7e73af56de848cdf617/airflow/operators/datetime.py#L67)
in this scenario it compares `target_lower < DAG logical_date < target_upper` so it also relevant when you backfill a task or clear historical runs because the date which will be compared is the DAG running date rather than current date.

Alternatively, note that the [target](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/602abe8394fafe7de54df7e73af56de848cdf617/airflow/operators/datetime.py#L51-L52) parameters accept also `datetime.time` so for scheduled runs you might want to use `datetime.time` rather than `datetime.datetime` for example to check if the time of running is between `08:00` to `10:00`

Comment: Please can you apply this to my examples?

Comment: The first paragraph is for your example. Today is `2022-05-28` so if the DAG runs it will follow `task_b`. It will always follow `task_b` because today/now is always greater than `target_upper` - this is why in the second paragraph I explained about  `use_task_execution_date` - If this comment makes it more clear let me know and I'll edit the answer

Comment: I gave a list of 3 specific execution dates

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. You didn't set `use_task_execution_date` so it doesn't matter what dates the DAG is executed. It will always be compared to now and in your case since now is `2022-05-28` it will follow `task_b` (the same for any future execution). See the source code condition https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/602abe8394fafe7de54df7e73af56de848cdf617/airflow/operators/datetime.py#L70-L73

Comment: My mistake, I assumed ‘use_task_execution_date’ was the default.

Comment: Sure NP. If solved your question please accept the answer